# PHP SELECT FROM multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a article pages, that i only want to show feed of the users that every account is following, kinda like twitter.
I have to distinct tables one is called `posts` other is called `followers`
I want to loop the articles but i want it to select only the users that my account is following.
I just need the `SQL` query that can  do that since the `PHP` part of the rest i can perform it

Something like this , although i know that this one does not work

```
$connect->query("SELECT id,userid,postagem FROM posts WHERE IN (SELECT followed FROM followers WHERE whofollowed = '$userd' )  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 13");
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `followed` is also a userid in the followers table:

```
$connect->query("SELECT id,userid,postagem FROM posts WHERE userid IN (SELECT followed FROM followers WHERE whofollowed = '$userd' )  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 13")
```

Comment: the userid must match in both

Comment: the query is saying "select all the posts of followed userids who are followed by the provided userid". You only need to match the provided userid against the followers table to get the userids which that user is following.

Comment: Its not looping, i need it to loop all posts that in followed the whofollowed have my username